# Self-study for quantum foundations and quantum gravitation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, resource-recommendations, education, foundations

I want to study quantum foundations, and also quantum gravitation.
What is a starting point?
(Although I have a ph.D of physics but I don't have sufficient knowledge about those topics.)
good review papers, websites, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Travis Norsen has an excellent [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319658662) on quantum foundations, certainly suitable for someone at your level.  It covers everything quite well except retrocausal models, which are explicitly set aside.  For that topic, you might look at this [Rev Mod Phys article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04313) which summarizes the motivation for using some future-input-dependence in models of quantum entanglement, as well as describing some of the retrocausal models in the literature.

Quantum Gravity, I'm not so sure about; I'll leave those recommendations to others...